# Why can't I instantiate a new object from a string without a full namespace

Tags: php, reflection, namespaces

Why is it that when I want to instantiate a new object from a string like so

```
use Foo\Bar\Test

$name = "Test";
$test = new $name();
```

I get an exception since `Test` is not found in the global namespace. 
I know I could simply use the full namespace when instantiating :

```
$name = "Foo\\Bar\\Test";
$test = new $name();
```

But it kind of doesn't fit the use I planned to make out of it. I know it's probably a design flaw on my part for the "doesn't fit" but it still raised the question as to why this cannot be done. Also, if it exists, are there alternatives to this approach? (beside `__NAMESPACE__` as in this example I am not currently in `Foo\Bar`).

Comment: Note: `Foo\Bar\Test` is *not* the full namespace, `\Foo\Bar\Test` is.

Comment: `why this cannot be done`. At a guess, use statements are dealt with at compile time, your second example will be determined at runtime.

Comment: @JonStirling Seems obvious now. I guess I was more looking for a work around but it think it's just time to review my design. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the information, the compiler resolves at compile and at runtime. At compiletime he resolves alias resolution.

```
use Foo\Bar\Test
```

So every occurance of `Test` would be resolved to `\Foo\Bar\Test`.

Creating *new* objects instead is an runtime operation. At this point, there isn't any alias or namespace resolution. The only thing the runtime (`new` operator) knows at this time, is the given name. If you pass a class, it must always be the full qualified name.